# Solve ODE's until an event occurs in Octave

Tags: matlab, octave, numerical-methods, differential-equations

In Matlab I know how to solve an ODE until an even occurs (for example, solve the ODE until the y-coordinate is zero):
http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/odeset.html#f92-1017470

Is there an analogy in Octave?

Here is the relevant code:

```
lsode_options('Events', @events);
t0 = linspace (0, 20, 1000);
[t,x,te,ye,ie] = lsode(@HH, ynot, t0);
```

Comment: I haven't used octave in awhile, but I think the infrastructure is there in [`odepkg`](http://octave.sourceforge.net/odepkg/). It has `odeset`, event handlers, etc.. Have you tried to adapt something like the simple matlab [ball ODE example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/math/f1-662913.html#f1-669698) to octave??

Comment: Yes, I tried something like that example (but even simpler), but it did not work.  I can get LSODE working in Octave, but the event template that I've used in Matlab doesn't seem to work in Octave.

Comment: When you say 'doesn't work' what happens exactly?

Comment: I get the warning: `warning: lsode_options: no match for "Events"` and then the error: `Invalid call to lsode.  Correct usage is:

 -- Loadable Function: [X, ISTATE, MSG] = lsode (FCN, X_0, T, T_CRIT)`

Comment: I included some of the code for you to look at.  Essentially the same code works in Matlab (of course you have to change lsode to ode45, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install the package `odepkg` from [Octave-Force](http://octave.sourceforge.net/). You may well already have this installed. You then use the ode solver functions from this package, which have identical syntax to the Matlab ode solvers, such as `ode45`. Note that the names of the solvers may not be identical, and you will need to find the appropriate one for your problem. `ode45` does appear to have an implementation in the latest version though.

Comment: Simce I wrote this answer ode45 and some other ode functions have been moved to core octave so you might not need odepkg. As well as this, odepkg has moved out of octave forge